# How to add 1 drawing with a button to JFrame ?

Tags: java, swing, drawing

My drawing class: for example I just want to draw a simple line

```
public class DrawNot1 extends JPanel {

private BasicStroke BS = new BasicStroke(2);
private int x;
private int y;

public DrawNot1(int x, int y){
    setSize(100, 100);
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){               
    super.paintComponent(g);
    doDrawing(g);
}

private void doDrawing(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setStroke(BS);

    g2d.drawLine(x, y, x, y+10);

}
```

my JFrame class:

```
public class Main extends JFrame{

private int x;
private int y;

public Main() {
    initUI();
}

public void initUI() {
    setSize(600, 500);
    setTitle("Points");
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    add(new DrawNot1(20, 20));
    add(new JButton("button1"));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Main ex = new Main();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

}

I want to show my drawing next to the button but that doesn't appear the only component that appear is the button, my drawing does not.

My ultimate goal is when I press the button my drawing is appear near the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` by default, adding two components to the default (`CENTRE`) position means that only the last one added will be shown.

Try adding the button to the `SOUTH` position instead

```
add(new JButton("button1"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

You may also find the overriding the `getPreferredSize` method of `DrawDot1` and providing a suitable value will also result in a better output

Comment: @AltianoGerung Yeah, it's a common gotcha ;)